# \dots alignment in math environment and amsmath

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath

In some cases, with amsmath, it seems that the dots are not well aligned. For instance, when in parenthesis, it is normally aligned, but when followed by a colon, it is in the middle of the line.

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
    $(\dots) = \dots:$
    \end{document}
```

Which gives the following result:

[image: misalignment of \dots]

Comment: that is the _whole point_ of `\dots` it chooses between `\ldots` and `\cdots` depending on the context,

Comment: Indeed egreg, somehow duplicate of the one you mentioned. But for my defence, if the title was more explicit than "how do magic \dots work in amsmath?", I would have saw it when I searched for "\dots alignment" ;-) (And for the sakeof completeness, the "\ldots" solution -which is exactly was I searched for- is only mentioned in a comment and not a full answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\dots` chooses between `ldots` (low dots) and `\cdots` (centered dots) depending on the context. You can always use the lower level commands directly if you do not like the choice it makes.

Or you can use the following semantically oriented dots versions (from the amsmath manual)

· `\dotsc` for "dots with commas"

· `\dotsb` for "dots with binary operators/relations"

· `\dotsm` for "multiplication dots"

· `\dotsi` for "dots with integrals"

· `\dotso` for "other dots" (none of the above)

Comment: Ok, I didn't know the existence of \ldots. And now you mention it, it makes it logical. thanks ;-)